# Fastest way to reduce a list of objects

Tags: scala

I have a list:

```
case class Person(name:String, salary:Int, cars:Int, country:String)
    val a = Person("gin", 100, 2, "Ind")
    val b = Person("gin", 200, 1, "Ind")
    val c = Person("gin", 50, 1, "US")
    val d = Person("bin", 10, 0, "US")
    val e = Person("bin", 20, 2, "UK")
    val f = Person("bin", 30, 5, "Ind")
    val list = List(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I would like to reduce the above list based on name and country so the output will be

```
Person("gin", 300, 3, "Ind")
Person("gin", 50, 1, "US")
Person("bin", 10, 0, "US")
Person("bin", 20, 2, "UK")
Person("bin", 30, 5, "Ind")
```

My solution to this is:

```
listBuffer.groupBy(p => p.name -> p.country).map {
  case (key, persons) => key -> (persons.map(_.salary).sum, persons.map(_.cars).sum)
}.map {
  case ((name, coutry), (ss, cs)) => Person(name, ss, cs, coutry)
}
```

Is there a more efficient solution to the above problem?

Comment: You could get persons in one go without double map(..) on grouped collection

Comment: Can you show me how? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Nyavro's suggestion, you can (in order of decreasing abstraction level, and thus both increased efficiency and decreased composability):

1. Avoid intermediate collections in `persons.map(...).sum` by using `persons.view.map(...).sum` or more directly

   ```
   def sumBy[A, B](xs: Seq[A])(f: A => B)(implicit n: Numeric[B]) = 
     xs.foldLeft(n.zero) { (a, b) => n.plus(a, f(b)) }

   sumBy(persons)(_.salary)
   ```
2. For this case you can even do everything in a single pass:

   ```
   listBuffer.foldLeft(Map.empty[(String, String), Person]) {
     (map, p) =>
       val key = (p.name, p.country)
       map.updated(key, (map.get(key) match {
         case None => p
         case Some(oldP) => 
           Person(p.name, p.salary + oldP.salary, p.cars + oldP.cars, p.country)
       })
   }
   ```
3. Convert the above to a `while` loop (really not recommended unless you really need the performance).

Comment: First option looks great IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You can save some iterations like this:

```
list
  .groupBy(person => person.name->person.country)
  // Collect Persons in one go:
  .map {
    case ((name,cuntry), persons) => 
      // Collect total salary and cars in one go:
      val (ts, tc) = persons.foldLeft ((0,0)) {
        case ((salary,cars), item) => (salary+item.salary,cars+item.cars)
      } 
      Person(name, ts, tc, cuntry)
}
```